# How to send data to multiple firebase childs using for loop

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a social media app and to send news feed what im doing is sending the new post to all the users which are currently in friendslist of the current user.

[image: User contacts]

Firstly i get all the contacts user id using following method

```
friendList = new ArrayList<>();
    contactRef.child("Contacts").child(currentUser).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            friendList.clear();
            friendList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Log.v("data","nothing found");
            }else{
              for (int i = 0; i < friendList.size(); i++) {
                GetNewsFeed(friendList,i);
              }
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

then i use the friendslist to get the size and run it thorugh the for loop to send the post to each user's newsfeed.

```
share_post_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String post = user_post_status.getText().toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(post)){
                showMessage("Type something first ");
            }else{
                DatabaseReference userMessageKeyRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(currentUser).push();
                String key = userMessageKeyRef.getKey();
                type = "text";
                for (int i = 0 ; i < friendList.size() ; i++){
                    sendPostToFriendsNewsFeed(type, key, post, friendList, i);
                }
                sendPostToProfileFeed(type, key, post);
                user_post_status.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    private void sendPostToFriendsNewsFeed(final String type, final String key, String post, List<String> userList, int i) {[enter image description here][1]
    Map textBody = new HashMap();
    textBody.put("post",post);
    textBody.put("type",type);
    textBody.put("name",current_user_name);
    textBody.put("photo",current_user_photo);
    textBody.put("date",saveCurrentDate);
    textBody.put("time",saveCurrentTime);
    textBody.put("key",key);
    textBody.put("uid",currentUser);

    newsFeedRef.child(userList.get(i)).child(key).updateChildren(textBody).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
            Log.v("sent",uid);
            Log.i("User post shared", "post type =" +type+ ", "+"postID = "+key+", "+"userID = "+currentUser);
        }
    });
}
```

'Log.v("sent",uid)' this message in onComplete displays the user id of the last child of friendlist.

[image: NewsFeed]

Comment: That's quite a bit of code. When you step through this code line by line in a debugger and inspect the value of each variable on every line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo for (int i = 0 ; i < friendList.size() ; i++){
                    sendPostToFriendsNewsFeed(type, key, post, friendList, i);
                } this should run for both the contacts of the user but instead it runs for only the last child

Comment: Have you tried to step through the debugger to see what goes wrong?